# Where can I find a video on Liouville Non-Critical String Path Integral?

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, path-integral

Would anybody know of a video lecture course in which [Polyakov's](http://qft.itp.ac.ru/polyakov-2.pdf) non-critical [string path integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_field_theory)

$$Z = \int D [\psi(\xi)]\, \, \exp \left\{ \frac{D-26}{48 \pi}\int_{\xi}\left(\tfrac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \psi)^2+\mu^2e^{\psi}\right) \right\}$$

is fully derived? Hopefully it's part of one of the many string theory courses online, perhaps someone has come across it.

The result is *very briefly sketched* at the very end of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uzd0oZyVBiE) and continued into the beginning of [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kV0nVocrEI4), it's so inspiring I'd love to see this fully developed.